# How to use an Android SearchView without singleTop?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity that I normally want to exist in multiple tasks, so that the [Back] button restores a previous state; however, I also want to use a [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) with an existing activity, without pushing a new one onto the task stack (since I want to search what's currently displayed).  Here's my problem:

- If I set the activity's launch mode to "singleTop", the SearchView works with the current activity, but [Context.startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) does not add new activities to the stack.
- If I set the activity's launch mode to "standard", *startActivity* adds new activities to the stack, but SearchView also creates a new (empty) activity, instead of searching the existing one.

I can't find any way make SearchView use intent flags (e.g. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).  I tried going the other way around, setting launch mode to "singleTop" then adding [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to every intent, but that worked only when launching from a different activity class; when I try to launch a new instance of an activity from its own class, Android didn't respect FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and didn't push a new task onto the stack.

Perhaps there's something I can do in [Activity.onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to force the activity to clone itself then.

I'm on the verge of giving up on SearchView and just writing my own custom widget, despite that fact that *"Beginning in Android 3.0, using the SearchView widget as an item in the action bar is the preferred way to provide search in your app"* ([Source](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)) — so far, it seems just too inflexible and non-configurable to be useful in non-trivial cases.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: From the total lack of responses (and low number of views), I'll guess that this is a non-trivial problem.  There is another possible work-around (besides just avoiding SearchView): I could design the singleTop Activity to maintain its own state stack and switch states, then intercept the Back button to simulate moving through the task stack.  I have a strong aversion, though, to replacing core OS functionality with simulations — if that's the only option, I'll just decide that Google recommended SearchView prematurely for production use, and will create my own search action component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of reflection and false starts, I realized that SearchView was simply the wrong thing for this task.  Google designed SearchView with a very specific type of search activity in mind:

- The user types in a search query.
- The app pushes a new activity showing a list of results.

That's not the search model I was using; instead, I wanted to refine a list currently shown on the screen using the query — it was more of a filtering search than a synchronous query and response model.  SearchView is not designed for that, so I went ahead and wrote my own widget (and bound it to the search menu item and the search button).

I'm surprised that no one had any comments on this question — usually Android questions generate a lot of discussion.  I guess that this was was just too far out there.

Comment: I was wondering about whether I can use SearchView for filtering already visible items, too! Thanks for underlining that SearchView is intended to have another action started! I had exactly the same question in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Lars — I was starting to think I was the only one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP, but have a solution that doesn't mean giving up on using `SearchView`. It's not the perfect solution, but it's fairly clean and seems to work well.

As the OP stated...

> when I try to launch a new instance of an activity from its own class, Android didn't respect FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and didn't push a new task onto the stack

...so my solution is to go via an intermediary Activity. For this, I created a `DummyActivity` class which basically takes the original intent and forwards it on to your destination activity.

So, from my original activity, instead of calling...

```
Intent destinationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DestinationActivity.class);
startActivity(destinationIntent);
```

...I call...

```
/*
 * Create the intent as normal, but replace our destination Activity with DummyActivity
 */
Intent dummyIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DummyActivity.class);

/*
 * This will make it so that if user clicks back from the next activity, they won't be shown DummyActivity
 */
dummyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

/*
 * Tell DummyActivity about the destination Activity
 */
dummyIntent.putExtra(DummyActivity.EXTRA_DESTINATION_ACTIVITY, YourDestinationActivity.class); //IMPORTANT - the destination Activity must implement Serializable

/*
 * If you want, you can add any other extras to dummyIntent (which will be passed through to the destination activity). Launch DummyActivity.
 */
startActivity(dummyIntent);
```

In my manifest, DesinationActivity is defined as singleTop.

And the only other thing you should need is the DummyActivity class which shouldn't need any major customising...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DummyActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DESTINATION_ACTIVITY = "uk.co.mobilewebexpert.EXTRA_DESTINATION_ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        /*
         * Get destination activity info
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<Activity> destinationActivity = (Class<Activity>) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_DESTINATION_ACTIVITY);
        Bundle destinationActivityExtras = intent.getExtras();

        /*
         * Launch destination activity
         */
        Intent destinationActivityIntent = new Intent(this, destinationActivity);
        destinationActivityIntent.putExtras(destinationActivityExtras);
        destinationActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(destinationActivityIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Override super.onNewIntent() so that calls to getIntent() will return the latest
     * intent, rather than the first intent.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will work for you, too. Suggestions welcomed. Cheers.