# How to override android:launchMode="singleTop"?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `SearchActivity` that is defined with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest.

My `SearchActivity` includes a `SearchView` for the user to enter their query and a `ViewPager` to show the search results.

I chose single top for `SearchActivity`, so the use can make loads of searches in the activity and then only has to press the Back button once to get back to the home screen.

However, I have just introduced a "SmartSearch" button into the activity which, when pressed, will trigger an automatic advanced search with the results still shown in a `SearchActivity`.

The requirement, though, is that I need these advanced search results to show up in a new activity on the stack - i.e., so the when the user presses Back, they will be taken to the previous (standard) results screen, and then must press Back a second time to get back to the home screen.

I've read [this about launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and this [about tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), and have tried launching the 'advanced' `SearchActivity` using an intent like this...

```
smartSearchIntent.putExtra(SearchResultsActivity.QUERY_EXTRA_KEYS, selectionArgs);
smartSearchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

...and I also tried using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as the parameter, but when I press Back on the advanced search results screen, it just jumps straight back to the home screen.

All the while, I have `android:launchMode="singleTop"` defined in the manifest for this activity because that is the 'normal' behaviour - so is it possible to override this and, if so, how?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Would it be possible to make your Advanced search a new Activity that extends from your `SearchActivity`?  You'd have to register it in the Manifest as "standard".  The other option is refactoring so `SearchActivity` is standard and every time you start `SearchActivity`, you set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

Comment: The second option sounds more appealing, but not sure how to modify the intent that creates the first `SearchActivity` as the search intent is handled internally by the `SearchView`...

Comment: DeeV, I had a slight issue with the second approach when trying to navigate the back stack. I have now implemented your first approach and it works very well and was easy to implement. Would you like to provide it as an answer and I tick select it as the best solution.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use a SearchView so I didn't know how to get around it. I do not think it is actually possible to overwrite a Manifest attribute as those are read by the system when it's instantiating Activities.

Comment: We're not actually overriding the manifest attribute itsrlf, but overriding it's influence on how the activity is launched. As presented in the link in my answer, this doesn't always work as expected, but your first suggestion solved my original/underlying problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution / workaround for this. Have just posted my answer for someone with a related problem, here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125107/1617737 .