# Ignore activity launch mode from manifest

Tags: android

Suppose I'm inside activity A, which is currently on top of stack and A's launchmode in manifest is singleTop. Is there a way to launch another instance of A from A. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

With singleTop launch mode current activity just gets new intent.
In other words is there a way to ignore manifest launchMode?

Comment: Why not remove the `launchMode` from the manifest and use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` for the times you want it to be single top?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791224/how-to-use-an-android-searchview-without-singletop/27125107#27125107 this seems related, see if it can help